# Inject javascript into SwiftUI WebKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, webkit

How would I set the text size of a SwiftUI WebKit View to a @State variable? I have this code that allows me to use WebViews in SwiftUI

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {

   var url : URL;

   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
       return WKWebView();
   }

   func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
       uiView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
   }
}
```

I saw [this](https://github.com/yamin335/SwiftUIWebView/blob/b588cfbb0e17dad5a3d5a5fd8754ae43129ca7de/SwiftUIWebView/WebView.swift#L90) and tried to replicate it,

```
    class Coordinator : NSObject {
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, js : String) {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript(js)
        }
    }
```

But I wasn't able to get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this in navigation delegate, after loading did finish, as shown below:

```
class Coordinator : NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    // ... any other code

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: { (value, error) in
             // .. do anything needed with result, if any
        })
    }
}

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {

   var url : URL;

   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
       let webview = WKWebView()
       webview.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
       return webview
   }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

   func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
       uiView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
   }
}
```